# calculate std for Pandas DataFrame grouped by object data type column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have pandas dataframe with numeric and object data type columns

[image]

code of input

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'country_code': ['AFG', 'AGO', 'ALB', 'ARE', 'ARG'],
    'country_name': ['Afghanistan', 'Angola', 'Albania', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Argentina'],
    'continent': ['Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'South America'],
    2010: [11.35, 9.43, 14.09, 2.48, 7.71],
    2011: [11.05, 7.36, 13.48, 2.30, 7.18],
    2012: [11.34, 7.35, 13.38, 2.18, 7.22],
    2013: [11.19, 7.37, 15.87, 2.04, 7.10],
    2014: [11.14, 7.37, 18.05, 1.91, 7.27]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i try to calculate stdev for the dataframe columns grouped by object data frame column(continent).

so if i have columns with object data type i should get the numeric one's, but the problem is when to get the numeric columns i will not able to see the the object data type column(continent).

```
df.select_dtypes('number').groupby('continent').std()
```

is there another way to make it ??

Comment: `df.groupby('continent').std(numeric_only=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have thid `df`:

```py
  country_code country_name continent  2010  2011
0            A            A    Europe     1    40
1            B            B    Europe     2     5
2            C            C   America     3    60
3            D            D   America     4     7
```

Then you can do:

```py
out = df.groupby("continent").apply(
    lambda x: x.select_dtypes("number").std(), include_groups=False
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
               2010       2011
continent                     
America    0.707107  37.476659
Europe     0.707107  24.748737
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Series as a grouper, the column doesn't need to pre-exist in the DataFrame:

```
df.select_dtypes('number').groupby(df['continent']).std()
```

Alternatively, use the `numeric_only=True` parameter of [`groupby.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.std.html) to automatically filter out the non-numeric columns:

```
df.groupby('continent').std(numeric_only=True)
```

Output:

```
                   2010      2011      2012      2013      2014
continent                                                      
Africa              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
Asia           6.272037  6.187184  6.477098  6.470027  6.526596
Europe              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
South America       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```